# Quiver vectors superimposed on a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot y vs x line, then on top of it I would like to plot vectors. I can do this using `plot` and `quiver` functions of matplotlib. However, the vectors will always be drawn behind the line, not on top.  That is the line will be visible over the vector arrows.

**My question for all of you is... is there a way to put the quiver vectors on top of the previously plotted line?**

Answer (score 9):

You need to set the `zorder` of the quiver to be higher than the line.

```
x = range(15)
y = rand(15)
u = rand(15)
v = rand(15)

figure()
plot(x,y,'rx-',zorder=0)
quiver(x,y,u,v,zorder=1)
```

[image: example image]

Comment: @user1739116 if this solved your problem, can you please accept the answer?